# How to determine the coordinates of iPad's bottom right corner in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, ipad, landscape

I am trying to place a subview (`buttView`) in the *bottom right corner* in the main view (from code, not from IB).

The following code *works*

> ```
> const float bottom = self.frame.size.height;
> const float left   = self.frame.size.width;
> NSLog(@"bottom=%.1f left=%.1f", bottom, left);
> CGSize bz = buttView.frame.size;
> CGRect rc = CGRectMake(left-bz.width, bottom-bz.height, bz.width,bz.height);
> buttView.frame = rc;
> [self addSubview:buttView];
> ```

But I am *confused*, because, according to the log message, **bottom=1004.0  and left=768.0**, and the iPad *is* in **landscape mode!** (The width should be larger than the height!??)

Moreover, if I *turn off "autoresize subviews"* in IB, then code will only work if I swap `bottom` and `left` (but it does not work perfectly because the true width is 1024 and not 1004).

*My question is: is there an elegant way to determine the location of the view's bottom right corner when the view is in landscape mode?*

Comment: +1 for a well-formed post that includes code, what you've tried, and a specific, answerable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at those values in viewWillLayoutSubviews, and you use bounds instead of frame, you will get the correct values, and they will be updated if you rotate the device.